# TimeCreated property not returning unique value Get-AzureRmDisk

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to extract date creation of os-disk in azure portal. I am able to generate os-disk lists from Get-AzureRmDisk cmdlet.

however, when i try to extract timecreation date with -unique parameters. the results shows duplicate values

```
 $disks = Get-AzureRmDisk -ResourceGroupName "testGroup"
 $osdisk = $disks.Name -match '-osdisk'
```

Result :

[image]

```
$datess = $osdisk.TimeCreated | Select-Object -Unique
 $datess
```

Result :

[image]

As we can see there is an additional duplicated date which is being displayed. Any suggestions on how i can get date of the particular Azure os  disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could format the `TimeCreated` value into the Date Time format which is easier for comparison and duplicate filtering.

The result of the code below is either `True` or `False`:

```
$osdisk = $disks.Name -match '-osdisk'
```

Please see the suggested changes:

```
$osdisk = $disks | where {$_.Name -match '_osdisk'}
$datess = $osdisk.TimeCreated | %{Get-Date $_ -f 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'} | Select -Unique
```

The changes have been tested working.

Comment: I got the following error

`Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. Exception setting "Date": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"."

At line:1 char:44

+ $datess = $osdisk.TimeCreated | %{Get-Date $_ -f 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ...

+                                            ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand`

Comment: Please see the updated answer and try out the suggested changes

Comment: awesome... thanks ...  
`$osdisk = $disks | where {$_.Name -match '_osdisk'} is same as $osdisk = $disks.Name -match '-osdisk' right?`

Also, can you explain by providing Get-Date format how it removed the duplicate date?

Comment: No they aren't the same. The first returns the list of disks which match the name 'osdisk' and the latter only returns true/false. Also as mentioned in my answer, the Get-Date format conversion makes the date time comparison easier and thus the duplicate filtering also straightforward